# Disable thumbnail creation for specific folders only, but all users

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails, nemo

How do I prevent my Ubuntu 14.10 (now 15.04) from creating and saving thumbnails for a specific folder only?
I want to tell the thumbnailer to skip over that single folder (and subfolders), but for all existing and future user accounts.

I read some answered questions about excluding a specific file type, but I need to exclude files by their location!
What I already tried is to hide the folder (renamed to `.foldername`), but with no luck. The folder is owned by root, by the way.

Comment: Just the start of an idea (and it will work for a single user only): the thumbnails are created, if I understand correctly, by hashing the path and writing a file called [hash].png to a directory `.thumbnails/normal/` and/or `.thumbnails/large/` in the user's home directory. Your program could perform the same hash and write a zero-byte thumbnail file instead. By any luck, the thumbnailer routine will notice that a thumbnail file already exists and skip thumbnailing your image.

Comment: What thumbnailer do you use? Where do you save the thumbnails?

Comment: @daltonfury42 I can't tell you. The situation where I specifically needed this was on an old, now dead laptop. I was running Ubuntu with XFCE there, so I think it was tumbler or however its thumbnailer was called. Anyway, I think if this is possible, it should be a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [@Fabby](https://askubuntu.com/users/344926/fabby) answer:

1. Install the package inoticoming

   ```
   sudo apt-get install inoticoming
   ```
2. Create wrapper script `disable_thumbnails`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   # Create the thumbnail filename
   tn_filename=$(echo -n "file://$1/$2" | sed 's/\s/%20/g' | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')

   # Destroy the thumbnail without deleting
   find ~/.cache/thumbnails -type f -name "$tn_filename*" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file; do
     echo > "$file"
   done
   exit 0
   ```
3. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x disable_thumbnails
   ```
4. Kill running processes, if necessary

   ```
   killall inoticoming
   ```
5. Watch your folder

   Avoid a trailing `/` for the folder names

   ```
   inoticoming "<path_to_disabled_thumbnail_folder>" <full_path_of_disable_thumbnails_script>  {} "<path_to_disabled_thumbnail_folder>" \;
   ```

There is only one problem. The changes are only visible after `nautilus -q`

Use `inoticoming --foreground …` to avoid the daemon mode, if you test the script.

Comment: Okay, the `nautilus -q` kills the nautilus background process and releases thumbnails cached in memory, I guess. And why is there the `\;` at the end of the `inoticoming` command?

Comment: @ByteCommander  To mask the `;` We need the `;` in the command and not as delimiter for the next command.

Comment: And what is this about `inoticoming --foreground _`? What's wrong with daemon mode? I thought it should run automatically in the background. Oh, and how do I set this thing to start automatically?

Comment: @ByteCommander To test the script use `--foreground`

Answer (score 2):

To get the file name for the thumbnail, start `md5sum` for the original file name:

```
% echo -n "file:///home/user/Pictures/image%201.png" | md5sum
6e1669aea9c118cb2b7ad23fc6646c71  -

% find ~/.cache/thumbnails -type f -name "6e1669aea9c118cb2b7ad23fc6646c71*"
/home/user/.cache/thumbnails/large/6e1669aea9c118cb2b7ad23fc6646c71.png
```

Now remove the read permissions:

```
chmod -r /home/user/.cache/thumbnails/large/6e1669aea9c118cb2b7ad23fc6646c71.png
```

Restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

and you will have no thumbnail for `/home/user/Pictures/image 1.png`.

Now you only have to write a script that scans your particular folders and do the above steps automatically.

<sub>[Credits  **:P**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/143742)</sub>

Comment: If you add that script and include a line that _overwrites_ the thumbnail with a 0-byte file, I will be happy! Oh, and you have to tell me (or link) how to get the script to run automatically. Best would be to react on file system events in that folder, if this was possible... I have no idea how to give you that bounty though, I guess @A.B. Has to do that as he offers it...

Comment: @ByteCommander something like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/623155/367165)?

Comment: @A.B. Yes, looks good. If you would now write another answer with that script and everything together, that would be awesome! :-)

Comment: @ByteCommander done :)